# Identify characters that do (not) appear in a string

Tags: python, string

Let's have the following string (in Python):

```
str = "There are times when your best efforts are not good enough"
```

Now, is there an efficient way to find the English alphabets (or even the special characters) that didn't appear in that string?

For example, in that string, the alphabets that didn't appear are: `c, j, k, l, p, q, v, x, z`

Thanks.

Comment: ASCII:  Use a flag array of size charset initialized to 0, for each character in the string change flag [ ch ] = 1.  Unicode: use a map of [ ch ] => 1 since it will be sparse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use sets:

```
import string

teststr = "There are times when your best efforts are not good enough"
alphabet = set(string.ascii_lowercase)
alphabet - set(teststr.lower())
# {'c', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'p', 'q', 'v', 'x', 'z'}
```

Use the string module to load all the letters into a set. A set is also unique, which is useful for the purpose of a) being fast and b) being directly related to your question.

Note I renamed your variable `str`, which is also the name of a built-in of Python that you do not wish to overwrite.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works great. But, as you may have noticed, the question was originally targetting Java rather than Python. Any clues on how to perform this in Java.